# How to scroll a Column to a new position whenever a ViewModel emits a new value?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a case where I have a ViewModel that emits scroll values to a `StateFlow`. Now, my Composable view should scroll to the most recent value, but I can't figure out how to achieve that.

My view model looks something like this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val scrollFlow = MutableStateFlow<Int>(0)

    fun getScrollFlow(): StateFlow<Int> = scrollFlow.asStateFlow()
}
```

And my view is like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyScrollingView() {
    val viewModel = viewModel()

    val scroll by viewModel.getScrollFlow().collectAsState()
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)

    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
        // Content here
    }
}
```

The thing here is, how do I make the scroll state to react to the values coming from the view model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many way to achieve that, for example:

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)

rememberCoroutineScope().launch {
    viewModel.getScrollFlow()
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
    .onEach{scrollVal ->
        scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollVal)
    }.collect()
}
```

Actually I'm afraid that code could be launched on every recomposition and is not ideal so maybe:

```
remember{
    viewModel
    .getScrollFlow()
    .onEach{scrollVal ->
        scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollVal)
    }
}.collectAsState(0, Dispatchers.Default)
```

or

```
val scroll by viewModel.getScrollFlow().collectAsState(0, Dispatchers.Default)
LaunchedEffect(scroll){
    crollState.animateScrollTo(scroll)
}
```

Comment: The last one worked nicely, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it inside a `LaunchedEffect` and use the scrollFlow value as its `key`, every time the scrollFlow emits new value, the `LaunchedEffect` will trigger its block.

```
@Composable
fun MyScrollingView() {
    val viewModel = viewModel()

    val scroll by viewModel.getScrollFlow().collectAsState()
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)

    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
        // Content here
    }

    LaunchedEffect(scroll) {
        scrollState.animateScrollTo(0)
        //or
//        scrollState.scrollTo(0)
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure if this would work in your case especially having this statement inside your composable though.

```
val viewModel = viewModel()
```